# What is the significance of Puppet and SVN in the WSO2 API Manager architecture?

Tags: wso2, api-manager

WSO2 recommends having Puppet & SVN as part of the API Manager architecture. But I have not found documentation that clearly states what this is required for. If someone can help me here with the actual reason for these tools that would be great. Can I use other tools that perform the same functions?

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions, we had SVN based deployment synchronizer mechanism to share API artifacts between gateway nodes. Now we recommend and encourage to use a shared file system between gateway nodes. Another option is to use Rsync between gateway nodes.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Distributed+Deployment+of+the+Gateway

Puppet is just a configuration management tool. This is not mandatory and you can use puppet to manage your configuration in a cluster. With Puppet you can automate your deployment creation and it would allow you to easily manage several clusters.